# Does a thrown exception retain its type if the throws clause lists only a super type of the thrown exception

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code, which analyze the basic behaviour of java exception handling (pre Java 7,no try-with-resources or multi catch or else).

I created a custom exception hierarchy to test this class,which is at the bottom of the file.

```
public class Rethrow {

  public void method1() throws MyExceptionSub1 {}

  public void method2() throws MyExceptionSub2 {
    try {
      method1();
    }
    catch (MyExceptionSubSub1 e) {}      // catch MyExceptionSub1 and all its subclasses
    catch (MyExceptionSub1 e) {}    
    //catch (MyException e) {}           // unreachable catch clause
    catch (Exception e) {}               // catch block with Exception is always reachable (by unchecked exceptions)
    throw new MyExceptionSub2();
  }

  public void method3() throws MyExceptionSub2 {
    try {
      method2();
    }
    catch (MyException e) {       // even if MyExecptionSub2 is caught by a catch block with MyException it retains its original type...
      e.printStackTrace();
      //e.method();               // ...but inside the catch block is of type MyException 
      throw e;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
  }

}

// Custom exceptions hierarchy

class MyException extends Exception {}

class MyExceptionSub1 extends MyException {}

class MyExceptionSub2 extends MyException {

  public void method() { System.out.println("sub2"); }

}

class MyExceptionSubSub1 extends MyExceptionSub1 {}
```

In particular, I would like to know this:

when a method DECLARE to throw an Exception,even if it THROWS a subclass ot that exception, the exception retains its type and is caught by its corresponding catch block (that's why I'm alowed to use catch blocks with more specific types than declared by the method in the try block)?

when inside a catch block (that acts like a method,with the exception parameter and all) the exception retains its type (if it's rethrown the compiler wants me to handle or declare the original exception,even if inside a catch with a more broad exception) but it's treated as the catch parameter (I can't call specific methods inside the catch clause)?

It's a little confusing..

I added some comments to clarify my assumptions (which are confirmed by the compiler,but please tell me if I'm right or wrong)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349243/java-can-catch-blocks-be-polymorphic

Answer (score 0):

> when a method DECLARE to throw an Exception,even if it THROWS a subclass ot that exception, the exception retains its type and is caught by its corresponding catch block (that's why I'm alowed to use catch blocks with more specific types than declared by the method in the try block)?

Yes. The object retains its actual type, as always.

> when inside a catch block (that acts like a method,with the exception parameter and all) the exception retains its type (if it's rethrown the compiler wants me to handle or declare the original exception,even if inside a catch with a more broad exception) but it's treated as the catch parameter (I can't call specific methods inside the catch clause)?

Yes. The declaration of the parameter applies, as always.

Comment: yes but "as always" it's a little tricky to apply here.
An object always retains its dynamic type,but when it's passed to an returned from methods,its static type may vary (upcast). 
This is not the case with throws and catch clause isn't it?

Comment: It is the case always. I don't understand why you think otherwise, or why you think it's 'tricky'. It isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not a dynamically typed language. If you declare a method with a parameter of type `Object` and pass a variable of type `String` to it, you can only call methods of type `Object` on it if you don't use casts. You can check that the variable is a `String` using `instanceof`, cast it to a `String`, and call methods of `String`.

Exceptions behave in exactly the same way. A `catch` clause effectively performs an `instanceof` check using the type specified in the clause, and declares a parameter of that type. The actual variable stored in this parameter can have a different runtime type from the parameter of the catch clause.